# Summation with unit step function

Tags: summation

I am confused on why the following summation simplifies as it does.
$$\sum_{k =-\infty}^{\infty}\alpha^ku[k]u[n-k]\alpha^{n-k} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n}\alpha^n$$
Here, $u[n]$ is the unit step function. My understanding of this statement is the following. The lower bound was changed from $-\infty$ to $0$ because of $u[k]$, since the unit function is only $1$ for values $\geq 0$. Similarly, for $u[n-k]$, we have time shift and reversal. So $u[n-k]$ is defined for all values of $n$ from $[-\infty, n]$. Hence, the upper bound becomes $n$. That gets rid of the two step functions. However, how does the two alphas reduce to just $\alpha^n$? This is what I'm not able to understand.

Comment: You asked almost the same question there http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2194187/convolution-with-an-lti-system Do you read the answers ?

Comment: $u[k] u[n-k] = 1_{k \in [0,n]}$

Comment: @user1952009 I don't see how they're the same. And there is no answer, just a comment with no explanation.

Comment: You know what I mean. If you didn't understand something then explain it. Asking exactly the same question reveals you probably only want the solution of your exercice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $\alpha^k\alpha^{n-k}=\alpha^{n-k+k}=\alpha^n$. Therefore
$$ \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\alpha^{k}u[k]u[n-k]\alpha^{n-k}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\alpha^nu[k]u[n-k] $$
Then as you noted, $u[k]=0$ unless $k\geq 0$, in which case it is equal to $1$. Similarly $u[n-k]=0$ unless $n-k\geq 0$, i.e. $k\leq n$, in which case it is $1$. Therefore
$$ \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\alpha^nu[k]u[n-k]=\sum_{k=0}^n\alpha^n$$

Comment: Do the exponents not have to change as the limits change?

Comment: No, it's always $\alpha^n$.